# Shadow on white background

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made this like 6 years ago using softimage with mental ray as renderer:

[image]

I want to create the effect of having a shadow on a white background again using cycles as the renderer.

For now I did this using a blender build from here:
http://graphicall.org/1200
which supports a cycles shadow caster.

The problem is that the build crashes a lot during rendering. So I was wondering, is there any way to archive this effect using cycles in blender 2.78?

Comment: If you are trying to cast a shadow on _white_, then all you have to do is set the environment color to white. If you are trying to cast on _transparent_, you will need to fiddle with the layers and compositing nodes to get your setup just right.

Comment: Graphicall.org builds are unofficial, experimental in nature, third party provided builds, they are not meant for production and might be unstable. Shadow catcher is also experimental at this point and awaiting official release so you can't expect it to work flawlessly. Either wait for 2.79 or use one of the [nightlies from the official buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download). If an official release also crashes report a bug **if it is reproducible**